# how to call C# class.cs in ASP.NET without Code Behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, iframe

I don't know if it is possible, I tried many ways but nothing seems to work in the project I am working on.

Here is the deal : I've got an ASPX page that need to call a Web Service when a button is click. I can't use code behind and Page Method because my page can't inherit from

```
System.Web.UI.Page
```

And the convention at my work doesn't let us use code behind.

I've tried calling a ".cs" class with method like Ajax (Asynchronously and synchronously) with the "XMLHttpRequest". In my stand alone it worked fine but when I integrate it in the project it did not work (Iframe inside Iframe inside Iframe inside Master Page).

I can't use things like external Libraries (Jquery, ...). I'd like to know if inside the ASPX page I'm working on I can call with some other way my class.cs with the code I try to call.

I have :

```
<input type="button" onclick="callSomeJSfunction()" value="testC#" />
```

My JavaScript do some treatment (getting the text I need without all the DOM component like , , and only keep text inside

) then is supposed to call the server part with the call for the Web Service (I can't call the Web Service from JS because of the cross domain Issue).

And my class.cs calling the Web Service is :

```
namespace testProlexis

{
    public class prolexisWSCorrector
    {
        public static string callProlexis(string textToCorrect)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textToCorrect))
            {
                throw new Exception("pas de texte à corriger pour Prolexis");
            }
            prolexisWebServiceImpl.ProLexisService test = new prolexisWebServiceImpl.ProLexisService();
            prolexisWebServiceImpl.AnalyzerInput inPut = new prolexisWebServiceImpl.AnalyzerInput();
            prolexisWebServiceImpl.AnalyzerOutput outPut = new prolexisWebServiceImpl.AnalyzerOutput();

            inPut.text = textToCorrect;
            String info ="try5";
            outPut = test.analyze(inPut, working);
            int tytytyty = outPut.errors.Count();
            return textToCorrect;
}
```

I have no more idea how to do it, I'm a beginner in ASP.NET (I used to work in JEE). So if anyone has an idea or some tutorial that I can look to help me I'll gladly take it.

Thanks for your time trying to help me.

Comment: Can you create a regular ASPX page with code behind somewhere in your project?
Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you can't call a web service perhaps you could just load a regular aspx page and have it do the job for you?

Comment: "And the convention at my work doesn't let us use code behind." ??

Comment: @slayner , I am assuming that you created a webservice and want to consume it with the asp.net ? is it right?

Comment: @Webruster I am not the one that have create the Web Service but I want to consume it in my ASPX page. Moo-Juice yes they don't want any code behind (aspx.cs). I have to use this Web Service and I can't create another aspx page with code behind because I can't use code behind. This is why I try calling the Web service from the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to use C# in your aspx page without a code behind (not recommended) you can just add it in a script tag in your aspx page.

```
<script language="C#" type="text/C#" runat="server">
    public void DoStuff(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var proxy = new prolexisWSCorrector();
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="" runat="server" Click="DoStuff" />
```

Or

```
<input type="submit" runat="server" onClick="DoStuff" />
```

Comment: when I try your code the F12 menu ( I'm on IE11) tell me DoStuff() is null or undefined.

Comment: How are you calling it? It's server code so you have to call it from a server control. Or you would have to use a web method attribute.

Comment: how can I use a Web Method attribute if I can't make my page inherits System.Web.UI.Page. I have add a server control but nothing happen when I click (I don't get any error), I try with breakpoint in the class.cs but they don't stop the execution.

Comment: I can't use asp:button, I can only use input or button. I tried going by a JS that call it with  <%DoStuff();%> it doesn't give me any error but don't seems to work.

Comment: Use can use a regular input with runat="server". You'll need to use a submit to force a postback or the code will never run because it is runat server.

Comment: Ho, I did not know that you could have a runat="server" on an Input. I tried it and got this error message : « DoStuff » is undefined. The big fact is that I need it to be call with my JS because of all the back ground stuff that my JS do before calling the Web Service. But I think it can't be done

Comment: After several try I managed to make It work, I am going to work around it to call it from javascript and make it return value to my javascript. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In your Aspx form, javascript function like below,

```
         function callSomeJSfunction() {
               jQuery.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "YourForm.aspx/YourPublicStaticWebMethod",
                        data: "{'ID': '" + txtID.value+ "','Value': '" + txtYear.value '}",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (msg) {
                           /*Do Success*/
                              },
                       Error:function(er){
                            /*Do Error*/
                              }
                          });
                                       }
```

In your Aspx Form, code behind,

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static Function YourPublicStaticWebMethod(int id,string year)
{
 //Code Here
}
```

Comment: As I said I can't use code behind and I can't use external libraries like Jquery.

Comment: Then you should depend only on javascript

Comment: I can't because of the cross domain issue regarding JS call with Web Server, I've already try. I need to use the C# for the Proxy class it create and the authorization my work have with this kind of intranet application.